# Существуют ли In Memory Data Base (IMDB) в виде библиотеки?

Tags: база-данных, memory, кроссплатформенность

Всем привет!

Народ подскажите, существуют ли локальные версии In Memory Data Base в виде библиотек, чтобы на стороне клиента не надо было ничего лишнего доставлять, в идеале кроссплатформенное решение. Есть конечно вариант засунуть SQLite в оперативку, но имхо оно не для этого делалось.

Задача: обрабатывать большой объем данных на клиенте в реалтайме.

Comment: А язык то какой?

Comment: Не принципиально, я говорил про готовую либу, у которой есть интерфейс взаимодействия с любым языком будь то с / с++ / python или что-то другое.

Comment: Sqlite может работать как in-memory database. См. https://sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

Comment: Об этом я знаю, написано в посте, что можно, но нужен альтернативный вариант, ворочать базу в несколько гб в sqlight не комильфо

Comment: SQLite она называется. И чем это не комильфо? Не менее комильфо, чем другие варианты. Как минимум, конкретно этот тщательно оттестирован.

Comment: База может весить до 9гб, ворочать ее в sqllight - не уверен что решение окажется стабильным и производительным. А вообще хотелось бы найти аналоги и провести сравнительное тестирование, после чего выбрать наилучший вариант.